# How to send a lot of emails without tripping the alarms

Tags: email, spam, throttling, bulk

I need to send couple of thousand emails at once, all addresses are existing users of one domain. I was wondering if that would not cause receiving server to cry 'Spam!' at the sight of so many emails.

I was wondering if there would be a way to mitigate such risk - like say sending 100 emails every 5 minutes or so, so there is no say 6k email influx at once. Is there a 'good practice' rule of the thumb for throttling number of emails sent by my server?

SPF and DKIM is setup so it should not cause any problems.

Comment: Are the users on the same domain as the sending account?

Comment: No they are not